# Gravitational field of a sphere

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

First time working with triple integrals so Im getting a bit confused...

The gravitational field of a sphere is given as:

$$V(X,Y,Z)= \frac{1}{ξ}\int^{2\pi}_0d\phi\int^A_0dr\int dR$$

We are given a point P outside the planet to change the limits of integration to

$$ξ − A < R < ξ + A$$

ξ is the distance from center of the sphere P and radius of the planet is of 1

I'm not sure where to place these new boundaries, as in which integral to do first and whether any original boundaries are preserved.

Comment: Very confusing. What is the constant $A$? And the variables? What are the (original) limits or integration in the inner integral? "... distance from Point $P$..." to *where*?...

Comment: Edited to clarify P, unfortunately there was no information on A

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me either. The field from a homogeneous sphere  is equivalent to all the mass being in the centre of the sphere if you are on the outside. When you say sphere I guess you mean a solid one and not a shell. The two r's, $r$ and $R$, look out of context.